# No audio in DELL XPS 13 (Ubuntu 15.04)

Tags: sound, dell, pulseaudio, xps, 15.04

Today I installed Ubuntu 15.04 (desktop edition, 64 bit) on a DELL XPS 13 (model 9343) notebook. Prior to installation, I upgraded the computer bios to A03. The kernel I am running is 3.19.0-15. I have no audio/sound. Here is some info:

```
cribari@darwin4:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

EDIT: the additional info of the comment

```
$ lspci -nn | grep -i audio
00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller [8086:160c] (rev 09)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High DefinitionAudio Controller [8086:9ca0] (rev 03)
```

Comment: More info... lspci -nn | grep -i audio
00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller [8086:160c] (rev 09)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High DefinitionAudio Controller [8086:9ca0] (rev 03)

Comment: I have the same problem than you :)
Ubuntu 15.04 and Dell XPS 13 2015. My BIOS is also A03 and my kernel is `3.19.0-16` have you solved your problem ?
My outputs are the same except that I also have `card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3263 Analog [ALC3263 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0` for `aplay -l`.
According to http://bartongeorge.net/2015/04/09/4th-gen-dell-xps-13-developer-edition-available/, "All of the relevant patches have been backported and all functions will work out of the box." from April 15th on Ubuntu 15.04 but that's clearly not the case.

Comment: According to https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_13_%282015%29, updating to Linux 4.0 could improve the situation and update to Linux 4.1 could make it even better but the wl-broadcom driver will not work.

Comment: Please also add the output of `dmesg -t | egrep "(audio|rt286|INT343)"`

Answer (score 10):

The solution is [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1413446) (thanks to Paul Wall).

First try to do 2 cold reboot in Ubuntu (cold reboot means that do need to shutdown and power up and not reboot!).
If you still have no sound, try

```
sudo modprobe snd-soc-rt286
```

and then select the sound card in Systems Settings/Sound (for me, that worked).

If you want to have the module automatically load at start up, do

```
sudo nano /etc/modules
```

add this to the file

```
snd-soc-rt286
```

save and close it. Restart and your sound should be working without the need of `sudo modprobe snd-soc-rt286`.
You will still need, however, to do a cold reboot after using Windows.

Comment: Just needed that "cold reboot"... thanks! :)

Comment: Two Cold Reboots fixed perfectly for me too!

Comment: The cold reboot did bring some sound, but the volume control doesn't work: it remains fixed at boot time...

Comment: "Cold reboot" was the cure for me! Thanks!