# XPS 13 Kubuntu 16.10 audio jack white noise

Tags: kubuntu, audio-jack

All of a sudden my headphone jack is giving me a bunch of white noise and no sound...this noise starts at boot, NOT AT LOGIN.

(might be worth noting, pulseaudio is registering headphone insertion in "outpu devices" tab)
(also worth noting: pulseaudio seems to kill my audio when my laptop is docked)

```
lspci | grep Audio
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
```

Hmm, I checked alsamixer in terminal as per [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Dell/comments/4j1zz4/headphones_have_static_noise_with_ubuntu_1604_on/) but even if I mute "headphone mc b" static stays...could this be a hardware issue? how can I determine such?

`alsactl restore` gives me

```
alsactl: state_lock:125: file /var/lib/alsa/asound.state lock error: File exists
alsactl: load_state:1683: Cannot open /var/lib/alsa/asound.state for reading: File exists
...
```

`sudo alsactl restore`

```
alsactl: set_control:1461: Cannot write control '2:0:0:Clock Source 11 Validity:0' : Operation not permitted
alsactl: set_control:1461: Cannot write control '2:0:0:Clock Source 10 Validity:0' : Operation not permitted
```

Similar issues

- [Laptop headphone jack (alsactl restore)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768463/laptop-headphone-jack-produces-no-sound)
- [headphones not working pavucontrol](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545915/ubuntu-14-04-headphones-not-working)
- [Headphone jack not working? (analog-output-headphones.conf)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132440/headphone-jack-not-working)

These seem similar to my issue but I'm getting noise, just static..
Going to try the solutions from the last one which seems to have had the most traffic.  First point (analog-output-headphones.conf) adjustment doesn't work.  I also noticed I had a -2.conf file...hmm

"
This did not work on a 2013 Dell XPS 13 running Ubuntu 16.04. – Mark Stosberg May 19 '16 at 14:31 "

This issue should have my solution, but my power save is not on, so I am not sure what else it could be..[hissing noise over headphones Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632306/hissing-noise-over-headphones-only-in-ubuntu)

Also [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/860109/the-bad-old-noise-issue-in-the-headphones-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts) there is a script to play silence nonstop, but I again think this is for the slight noise in the background rather than a storm of white noise that has smitten me.

This issue [Constant noise in headphones](https://askubuntu.com/questions/728592/constant-noise-in-headphones) seems to be promising...describes my exact problem "now whenever I plug in my earphones there will be a constant static, no sound from speakers and no response to changing anything on alsamixer like volume levels or mic boost or anything" Seems like @deepakborania was having issues because of additions to alsa-base.conf.  I wonder if the lines added in the headphone jack not working issue are not helping...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613056/no-audio-in-dell-xps-13-ubuntu-15-04) make sure to do a full halt (ie not just a sudo reboot).  That solved my main issue of noise.  Then it was a matter of [getting pavucontrol and adjusting analog-output-headphones.conf](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132440/headphone-jack-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by running `alsamixer` and setting "Headphone Mic Boost" to 22.